# Inner join + group by - select common columns and aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say i have two tables

```
Customer
---
Id Name
1  Foo
2  Bar
```

and

```
CustomerPurchase
---
CustomerId, Amount, AmountVAT, Accountable(bit)
1           10      11         1
1           20      22         0
2           5       6          0
2           2       3          0
```

I need a **single** record for every joined and grouped Customer and CustomerPurchase group.
Every record would contain

1. columns from table Customer
2. some aggregation functions like SUM
3. a 'calculated' column. For example difference of other columns
4. result of subquery to CustomerPurchase table

An example of result i would like to get

```
CustomerPurchases
---
Name Total TotalVAT VAT TotalAccountable
Foo  30    33       3   10
Bar  7     9        2   0
```

I was able to get a single row only by grouping by all the common columns, which i dont think is the right way to do. Plus i have no idea how to do the 'VAT' column and 'TotalAccountable' column, which filters out only certain rows of CustomerPurchase, and then runs some kind of aggregate function on the result. Following example doesn't work ofc but i wanted to show what i would like to achieve

```
select C.Name,
       SUM(CP.Amount) as 'Total',
       SUM(CP.AmountVAT) as 'TotalVAT',
       diff? as 'VAT',
       subquery? as 'TotalAccountable'
from Customer C
inner join CustomerPurchase CR
on C.Id = CR.CustomerId
group by C.Id
```

Comment: Isn't `VAT` just `Total - TotalVAT`? Why can't you, therefore, just subtract those 2 expressions from one another?

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Assuming your `CR` alias should actually be `CP`. Assuming also the "some kind of aggregate" is also *sum* where `Accountable` = 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you just need the follow slight changes to your query. I would also consider for clarity, if you can, to use the terms *net* and *gross* which is typical for prices excluding and including VAT.

```
select c.[Name],
    Sum(cp.Amount) as Total,
    Sum(cp.AmountVAT) as TotalVAT,
    Sum(cp.AmountVAT) - Sum(CP.Amount) as VAT,
    Sum(case when cp.Accountable = 1 then cp.Amount end) as TotalAccountable
from Customer c
join CustomerPurchase cp on cp.CustomerId = c.Id
group by c.[Name];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into the case when syntax. One more question, what if there was more than single columns in Customer table that i wanted to include in the result. I feel like grouping by all the columns just so that i can use them in the select is nasty.

Comment: "Nasty" is really more about using the right tool for the right job; A different criteria could lead to a different implementation, for example doing the aggregations in a `cross apply`; Feel free to ask a different question if you have other requirements you are unable to solve!